# Is it possible to have submenu outside of menu element? I dont want submenu to be a child of menu

Tags: menus

Well as title say: 
Is it possible to have submenu outside of menu element? I dont want submenu to be a child of menu.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE!  You may get better answers if you give a little more detail or context about your situation.

Comment: Submenus are the menus that are child of another menu item in WordPress. You can create a different menu through WordPress. If you give more details of what you are trying to achieve I will update my answer to help you with your question.

Comment: Hey giannisrig.

I did post a article with more details but I thought it was confusing and that's why nobody answered. 

Let me try to explain better.
I need 3 level menu (main menu lvl1, submenu lvl2, and submenu lvl3(child of submenu lvl2).
With default Wordpress menu nesting, I can't archive design I want. I made a codepen for this post https://codepen.io/artyor/pen/yLLvKjL?editors=1000 .
The 1st HTML is default wordpress, while 2nd HTML part is something I want to archive.

I need different HTML markup for wordpress menu.
I heard for walker, but not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Hey butlerblog,

I did post an article with more details but I thought it was confusing and that's why nobody answered. 

Let me try to explain better.
I need 3 level menu (main menu lvl1, submenu lvl2, and submenu lvl3(child of submenu lvl2).
With default Wordpress menu nesting, I can't archive design I want. I made a codepen for this post https://codepen.io/artyor/pen/yLLvKjL?editors=1000 .
The 1st HTML is default wordpress, while 2nd HTML part is something I want to archive.

I need different HTML markup for wordpress menu.
I heard for walker, but not sure if it's possible.

Comment: That would be good info for your question - edit your question instead of posting it as a comment. And post the code in the question as well, instead of linking offsite.  Try to make your question as complete and clear as possible.  [Here's how to ask a good question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember - the more detail in your question, the more likely someone can answer it specifically.